# What does stand behind the formula: "watt = ampere * volt"?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power, si-units

I know the "watt = ampere * volt" formula, but I don't understand what it means.

So, let's start from the beginning.

Coulomb answers the question: how many electrons do you have (in a particular case)?
1 coulomb is 6.241509×10^18 electrons.

Ampere answers the question: how many electrons do you have per 1 second?
1 ampere is 1 coulomb / 1 second.
For example 2 ampere = ( (6.241509×10^18) * 2) electrons per 1 second.

Volts answers the question: how many electrons per second you have left after these electrons passed a conductor?
It means that some of your electrons were spent on heating a conductor.
volt = ampere * resistance.
For example volts = (( (6.241509×10^18) * 2) electrons per 1 second) * R.
Let's say R = 0.5.
volts = (((6.241509×10^18) * 2) electrons per 1 second) * 0.5.
It means, that half of our initial electrons will be spent for heating.

But why W = A * V?
In other words it means:
W = A * A * R = A^2 * R.
What does it mean? Why exactly A^2?

Comment: "Volts answers the question: how many electrons per second you have left after these electrons passed a conductor?" Not so The electrons are not "spent". They are still there, but just have less potential energy.

Comment: @mikestone are you sure? Electricity passing through a conductor heats it up. Heating takes energy. Energy is electrons. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Energy is not electrons.  Electrons can gain & lose energy, but they do not cease to exist when they lose energy.

Comment: Electrons can gain & lose energy? So is means that they should have variable charge. What is the unit of measure for the charge of an electron? @MichaelSeifert

Comment: No, electrons always have the same amount of charge.  The energy of electrons is either due to their motion (kinetic energy) or due to their electric potential (potential energy).  Both of these things change as electrons move through space.

Comment: Ok, so where exactly there is a mistake in my reasoning? Could you point it out? Amperes is not an electrons per second? It is energy per second? @MichaelSeifert

Comment: @mikestone already pointed out the mistake in your reasoning in the first comment.  The rest of your misunderstandings seem to stem from that misconception.  I've expanded a bit on how you should think about it in my answer below.

Comment: *R = 0.5* Resistance is not a dimensionless number.

Comment: Did you learn about how electrostatic potential (i.e., voltage) relates to electrostatic potential *energy*? You can’t understand $P=VI$ without understanding that.

Comment: *electrons will be spent* If they simply disappeared, how could charge be conserved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of voltage is incorrect. The voltage (potential difference) between two points (say, the terminals of a resistor) is the work required (energy in Joules) per  coulomb of charge (electrons) to move the charge between the two points. Current is the rate at which the charge moves between the two points, or coulombs per second. Voltage times current = Joules per coulomb times coulombs per sec = Joules per sec = watts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is classical definition. But listen. If V = A * R, it means that we takes our electrons (electrons per second) and multiply by resistance. And at the output we have fewer electrons. No?

Comment: No. Electrons into a resistor equals electrons out of the resistor for conservation of charge  (assumes no branch out of the resistor). What is lost is electrical potential energy supplied to the electrons by the voltage source which is converted to heat.

Answer (score 6):

Voltage is not "how many electrons per second you have left after these electrons passed a conductor", because electrons are not "spent" in the process.  Rather, voltage is the change in potential energy, per unit of charge, between two points in space (for example, between the two ends of a circuit element.)

Once this is clear, we can also see that if we multiply current times voltage we get
$$
\frac{\text{charge}}{\text{time}} \cdot \frac{\text{energy}}{\text{charge}} = \frac{\text{energy}}{\text{time}},
$$
which is an amount of power, as expected.

Note also that resistance itself has units of $(\text{energy}\cdot\text{time})/(\text{charge}^2)$.  (Divide the units of voltage by the units of current to see this.)  So saying that a resistance of 0.5 means that you have "lost" half of the electrons is incorrect.  Rather, resistance has to be thought of as a proportionality between the voltage across a circuit element and the amount of current flowing through it.